# Why is requests.get() returning an outdated website in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, get

Relevant line of code is :

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

Here's what I've tried so far :

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

and :

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests

ua = UserAgent()
headers = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

But the data I get is still not the current version of the website.
The website I'm trying to scrape is [this grocery store flyer](https://www.metro.ca/en/online-grocery/search?sortOrder=relevance&filter=%3Arelevance%3Adeal%3AFlyer%20%26%20Deals).
Can anyone tell me why the data I get is outdated and/or how to fix it?

**Update:** it works all of a sudden but I haven't changed anything so I'm still curious as to why ...

Comment: Hello Nads! could you check your status code please by doing a `print(response.status_code)` Are you getting a `200` status code? Thanks

Comment: Hi! Yes I did that and I do get 200

Comment: When I tried accessing the site you provided I got this tho `Error 1020 Ray ID: 60b34c018a9a1228 • 2021-01-02 09:01:42 UTC`

Comment: I ran it again and still getting 200, I googled your error and it seems like an Access Denied error to do with your firewall?